# Will Static sql (as opposed to Dynamic SQL) invalidate other packages in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

Hi
If I write a custom package with nothing but static SQL in it, would it invalidate other package. (other third party packages that were shipped as wrapped code).

a co worker suggests that I re write the custom package in Dynamic SQL, and I will not see this problem. I find this hard to believe because the third party packages are not dependent on my custom package, 
a compiled package should stay compiled, regardless.

-thank you

Answer (score 6):

It would only invalidate packages that included your custom package as a dependency.

You should be able to prove that to your co-worker (and yourself) in a test environment.

Comment: +1: Beat me.  It wouldn't invalidate the entire package, just the references.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling a new package won't invalidate anything. By definition, an existing compiled package can't refer to your new package that you haven't created yet.

*Recompiling an existing package* (that might have some references to it) could invalidate existing packages, of course.

Answer (score 0):

No. A package with DML statements would not invalidate any package at all.